# leaflet zoom control moving while dragging the map

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

When I drag the map to change location, the zoom controls moving it it to the middle of the map and disabling parts of the map, in the picture you can see the controls in the middle of the map, and when I try to click on the left side of the map its adding marker to the right side, like I clicked there.
When I drag the map, the copy rights line also moving to the right as you can see in the picture

[image: screenshot of my map]

Help please

```js
L.tileLayer('https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
                            maxZoom: 18,
                            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
                                    '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
                                    'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
                            id: 'mapbox.streets'
                        }).addTo(mymap);




 function checkWidth() {
                            var height = $(window).height();
                            $("#mapid").height(height - 150);
                        }

                        $(document).ready(function () {
                            checkWidth();
                            $(window).on('resize', checkWidth);
                        });
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please would you be able to provide a code sample (e.g. using Plunker / JSFiddle / SO code snippet…) that reproduces this issue?

Comment: the map code is just like the leaflet tutorial, but i use a jquery function to change the map size to the window size, but i dont think there is a connection.
 function checkWidth() {
                            var height = $(window).height();
                            $("#mapid").height(height - 150);
                        }

                        $(document).ready(function () {
                            checkWidth();
                            $(window).on('resize', checkWidth);
                        });

Comment: Sorry that is still not enough to reproduce your issue: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/TjifCfmQqThXHUt2 You might have some CSS interfering. Please make sure to share [enough code to reproduce the problem in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).